# Facebook Open Graph PHP and Javascript login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm building a website including an facebook login system. I thought it would be nice to use javascript on the clientside. Wich will proceed the authentication. After that an AJAX request will be made to my server to check some content into the MySql databases. The problem is that the PHP script doesn't recognise the Facebook session. I checked the cookies and there was no fbsr_[my_app_id] cookie. When I reloaded the page it was there and the AJAX request worked fine. Is there any way to get that cookie without reloading the page? Thnx in advance.

Comment: just do an ajax call to your "mysql"-script after the successfull login.

Comment: That wont help I'm afraid, because the login from facebook need to be confirmed and extended by the mysql data

Comment: what kind of server side interaction do you want, is there any facebook interaction with server side, if NO then your all task could be performed via Facebook-javascript-sdk. Reply me I can help you to get what you want.

Comment: I've made my own login system and now I want make the option to connect with facebook. I want to store on my server the users name, email, facebookID so I could save extra information just around it. Of course I could use the javascriptSDK to find all information and let ajax send it but that wont be safe. My current idear is log the user in to facebook with the javascript sdk and let php enter the session and get the data from facebook. But php only enters the session when there is a fbsr cookie. And that is there only after reloading the page and for php to get it, you must reload it twice.